# Net as an abbreviation for network?

Tags: meaning, abbreviations

I'm wondering if *net* is a suitable abbreviation for *network*. On the one hand, it sounds fine for me (maybe because I'm used to this terminology from the internet or similar). Apart from that, common dictionaries list different meanings for *net* (like woven material). Since English is not my mother tongue, I would be interested to hear how your perception is if you read *net* without reference to the full text (like at a title or logo). Does *net* directly let you think about e.g., a fisher net, or could it be a network too?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Where are you using the abbreviation? It's likely to be more suitable in some contexts than in others. For example, if you're talking about road networks rather than computer networks, referring to a road net might cause some confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your fast feedback. It is basically for a project that that links different partners. The name will be something like "Topic Network". For a logo or webpage we were now thinking about a short form "Topic Net".

Comment: [Neural nets](https://www.lexico.com/definition/neural_network) exist.

Comment: With no context at all (just NET printed on a piece of white card someone has just handed me) I’m *always* going to think fishing net, bird netting (keeping the birds off my fruit tree), mosquitoe net, butterfly net, etc before I think of the more complex, more figurative meanings of net like those associated with networks. “Topic Net” (with no context) sounds firstly like a device for catching topics before I begin to think of networks of topics.